# How to make ISOLINUX loaded RAMDisk writeable?

Tags: boot, mount, isolinux

I'm currently using [ISOLINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/ISOLINUX) to create a bootable MS-DOS 6.22 image in the RAM.

This is working pretty well! I can stuff the folders `CDROOT` and `isolinux` in this setup and then create a new ISO with an included BATCH file, which I then use on a bootable USB flash drive to be booted from.

The contents of `CDROOT` are marked as `A:` in the running DOS, contents of `isolinux` are then mounted on `D:`.

I tried to access those RAMDisks with simple MS-DOS commands like `MKDIR` or `DEL`. On `isolinux` this is perfectly possible.

But I don't have any write access on my mounted `CDROOT`. You may guess it, but I need write access there.

**How do I enable the mounted ISO as writeable in the mounted RAMDisk?**

Answer (score 0):

`CDROOT` is essentially a RO image; some of its contents is initially moved to a RW ram disk (D:); if you need to edit content from `CDROOT` you must move it first to a RW area. Please consider any edit is not persistent.